# How to improve linux debugging ability and be proficient in using linux

Tags: linux, debugging

how can I improve myself to be like a professional, especially what kind of materials can I read if any?

Comment: Some people are better than others at riding bicycles — because they do it. If you’re reasonably intelligent, and you’re capable of learning, and you use Linux, you will learn how to use it better.  Read whatever you can, starting with man pages.  When you run into a problem, search the web (including [SE]), read what you find, and try to understand it.  As a last resort, come here and ask a specific, intelligent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skill comes with a lot of practice, you should use Linux constantly and with time you will get better. Start by reading man page of any command you use, even if you know the basics of it for example: `ls` everyone used it, but not many understand what it does and how. Just read and practice also a must book to read is this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134277554).